# Same response data for all iterations even though cookie is cleared

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

My Test structure in Jmeter
Thread group (2 users)

- Http request
- Listener

For each iteration same form_key values are getting in response which should not be.
How to get unique form_key in response for each iteration
[Jmeter Test result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au3PG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using one of the online [Magento demo instances](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-demo.html), in particular this one: http://demo-acm-2.bird.eu/customer/account/login/

[image]

As you can see, each time `form_key` is different for each user for each iteration.

If you're using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) - make sure to tick "Clear cookies each iteration" box

[image]

Also make sure to properly setup the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, to wit put `http` or `https` into "Protocol", server name or IP to the relevant field, path, etc.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your response. I used the link that you shared above and I got different form_key values for each users. This is fine. I recorded a video in which i'm trying to get different form_key values but I couldn't https://www.loom.com/share/6dfaaa7fc1ae48bcb9fd6600b13e352b. Please watch this video and let me know if i missed anything. Here the request url www.partylite.co.uk/jasmine-jade-3-wick-jar-candle.html. Thanks